# Vuepress not displaying documents correctly

Tags: github, github-pages, vuepress

I updated a pre-existing vuepress documentation, which runs and works as expected when delopyed on localhost:8080/, however once I push the updates to gh hub pages it does not display correctly.

code i use to deploy:

```
set -e

npm run docs:build

cd docs/.vuepress/dist

git init
git add -A
git commit -m "Deploy documentation"

git push-f git@github.com:NAME/REPO.git master:gh-pages
```

I have no error messages durning run time or deploy.
But when I check the actual documentation on github, it displays funny. and the links do not work.... as when I check the pages dev eniroment on the console 404 errors appear... it seems that there might be something wrong with the dist.js files in assets....

Not sure how to fix this...please help. Thx!

Images 1: Displays black blocks 
Images 2 Error in the dev console
(I have no errors messages durning build only in the console)

[image: documentation veiw]

[image: chrome dev console error view]

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want to double-check if you have set the `base` correctly.

Check out the documentation site about [deploy to GitHub pages](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/deploy.html#github-pages) and [Config Reference -> base](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/config/#base)

---

If this doesn't solve your problem, can you post more detail about your code? Or maybe a repo?

Comment: i can not post repo here it is private.  the base is set correctly to the congfig directioins..  ```module.exports = {
    base: '/web-vagrant/',

    title: 'Web Vagrant',
    description: 'Web Vagrant Environment',```

Comment: i can share more  info about the code, what do you need? and also can i pm you instead?

Comment: Sun, I fixed it.... it was a base thing... but i had to take a closer look at the other titles.  Thank you!!!